# Does UIScreen have a notification for screen on?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to push a notification when the screen turns on, but I don't know how to detect that. Is there a way to detect when a UIScreen turns on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. The only (public) notifications associated with `UIScreen` can be found in the [UIScreen Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIScreenDidConnectNotification):

- UIScreenDidConnectNotification
- UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification
- UIScreenModeDidChangeNotification
- UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification

None of these will tell you when the device wakes up.

However, you can implement the `applicationDidBecomeActive(:)` method in your app delegate, which will be called when the device wakes up. Similarly, you can implement the `applicationDidEnterBackground(:)` method (also in your app delegate), which will be called when the device goes to sleep. Note that these delegate methods are called at other times as well (i.e. not only when the device transitions to or from sleep). But this is as close as you're going to get. See the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/) for more information.